# Try catch in async HttpClient call doesn't work as expected

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, async-await

I'm a little new to Android and Xamarin and async tasks in C#. I have an app with a splash activity that first checks for network connectivity, and then asynchronously checks the status of our the website via a get request to confirm that the website will show in a webview on main activity when it gets started. It checks for both non 200 status codes, and a general timeout, which happens when website is completely down.

I purposefully have web the server completely down so that requests will time out, to simulate that real life situation.

I set the timeout value as a property of the HttpClient instance. I thought that if anything times out, it should execute the catch which will change the TextView text that I have. But it never gets there. The app crashes after the exact timeout period I stipulated, so I guess at least my timeout is working. **It does change the textview text to "Checking website", so I know it's at least attempting it**.

I don't have access to the debugger, long story. So i'm hoping someone can just easily see a problem or misunderstanding I have. Hopefully the code provided is complete enough for the problem without having unnecessary things, but I can certainly ad more if needed. Thx.

```
public class Splash : Activity
{
    static readonly string TAG = "X:" + typeof(Splash).Name;
    TextView status = null;
    Button quit = null;
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.Debug(TAG, "SplashActivity");
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
        status = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.status);
        quit = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.quit);
        quit.Click += QuitApp;
    }
    protected override void OnResume()
    {
        base.OnResume();
        CheckConnection(this);
    }
    public void CheckConnection(Context context)
    {
        status.Text = "Checking connections";
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)context.GetSystemService(Context.ConnectivityService);
        if (cm.ActiveNetworkInfo != null && cm.ActiveNetworkInfo.IsConnected)
        {
            Task t = new Task(CheckWebsite);
            t.Start();
        }
        else
        {
            status.Text = "No Network Connection";
        }
    }
    public async void CheckWebsite()
    {
        status.Text = "Checking Website";
        string page = "http://example.com:6347/";
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        TimeSpan timespan = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(5000);
        client.Timeout = timespan;
        try
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(page);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                status.Text = "Connection OK";
                client.Dispose();
                response.Dispose();
                await Task.Delay(1000);
                StartActivity(new Intent(Application.Context, typeof(MainActivity)));
            }
            else
            {
                status.Text = "Cannot connect to website";
                client.Dispose();
                response.Dispose();
                quit.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
                await Task.Delay(2000);
                status.Text = "Connecting to Website";
                Task t = new Task(CheckWebsite);
                t.Start();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception err)
        {
            status.Text = "Connection attempt timed out";
            quit.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
            await Task.Delay(2000);
            status.Text = "Connecting to Website";
            Task t = new Task(CheckWebsite);
            t.Start();
        }                
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the `catch` block isn't being executed? Or aren't you seeing the side effects of its execution? You have several dangerous anti patterns in your code: `async void` and creating tasks using the `Task` constructor and starting them.